# BizTalk schema validation fails due to choice in schema

Tags: validation, xsd, schema, biztalk

Can someone figure out the solution to this issue? We have an integration with one receive location (WCF-BasicHttp). Due to some business requirement, that rcv-location had to be able to handle four different requests (with different schemas) being sent to it. So the only solution I could come up with was a schema containing those four schemas. Please take a look at picture below for clarity.
[image]

The receive location does have Microsofts standard receive pipeline XMLReceive set. And
So the solution works and receives the requests perfectly.

Now my issue is how to validate the requests (schemas) that do come in to us. I did try to set the SchemaDocSpec (for the schema above that you see) in the rcv pipeline with the hope that BizTalk would figure out validation. But that simply returns a 500 error back.

When the rcv location recieves (one of the four possible requests) the test request, it looks like below picture shows.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea on what I could do or try to fix this issue? Please let me know if you need more information from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have 4 separate schemas and set the Validate = True on the XML disassembler.

Or create a custom pipeline in Visual Studio and add the schemas there.

1. Add a Receive Pipeline to your solution
2. From the Toolbox add the XML disassembler into the Disassemble stage.
3. Add the XML Validator into Validate stage
4. In the XML Validator Pipeline Component Properties click on the ... button next to (Collection)[image]
5. In the Schema Collection Property Editor select the schema you want and click Add
   [image]
6. Repeat for the other schemas
7. Click OK when all added.
8. Deploy your solution and in the BizTalk Admin console, select the custom pipeline you created on the receive location.

Comment: Hi @Dijkgraaf. How am I to have four different schemas? I assume you mean that I put the four schemas in the 'DocumentSpecNames'. If that is what you mean, how do I separate the four different schemas? With a pipe sign ( | ) beteween every schema spec name?

Comment: @Emperor2052 Usually I find it easier to create a custom pipeline in Visual Studio, and add the schemas there.  Trying manually to do it in BizTalk Admin console usually results in tears.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with ading the schemas to the pipeline. Can you perhaps point me to a tutorial that sheds some light to this. (Yes, I do understand what you mean with the tears, haha)

Comment: Yup, it's error prone, but manual DocSpec/EnvSpec:
Use notepad or the likes. Locate the document schema(s). View propeties, copy-paste name + "," + FullAssemblyName on single line
Repeat for all document schemas.
search & replace "enter/linefeed" with ";".
Copy-paste single line from notepad into BizTalk 'property sheet'.
Repeat for enveloppe Schema.

Comment: @Emperor2052 I've updated my answer with how you can add the schemas to the pipeline.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, I tested this out and I still do get 500 internal error. It does not matter if I even use one schema to validata against, still the 500. However, only using XMLReceive-pipeline makes the solution work, but naturally without any validation. This is really unfortunate.

Comment: @MarvinSmit, I also tried to do that manually but dont follow what you mean with the 'BizTalk property sheet'. Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: When setting the values on a pipeline from the BizTalk management console. That's a 'Property sheet'. Or PropertyGrid Control.

Comment: @MarvinSmit, thank you. Will experiment a bit with this.